# Delete the history of an entire repository directory or delete commits with a given message in Git

Tags: git

I have a Git repository with a pretty long history. One of the directories in the repository is tracked, but consists of generated content. The size of the repository is becoming a problem and it is due to the changes in the generated directory, which are derivable from the other contents of the repository (it is only tracked due to certain tooling constraints). That means that the history of this one directory in particular is not very important, but for the rest of the repository, it is.

As I'm looking at ways to reduce the size of the repository without losing helpful history, I've identified two ways: either delete the history only for the files in this directory, in effect deleting history of this generated directory, or delete all commits which have a certain commit message, because in this case, the directory is only ever changed by commits with a certain commit message. Unfortunately, a better filter, like the contributor name or email, cannot be used as the automation which generates the directory impersonates one of the contributors to the repo.

Which of these two approaches are doable in Git? And if both, which might be better? Are there any approaches I am missing? I only have limited experience with amending Git repo history, usually to fix commit messages or wipe the evidence of existence of certain files, like secrets and keys. I want to inform myself before I unleash such a large scale change on a repository.

I don't think I need to add this, but just in case: the repo is hosted on GitHub and I assume I can just force-push to GitHub after carrying out the changes to make sure the history on GitHub gets updated the same way. I don't expect there are changes I could make which would work locally but not be transferrable to specifically GitHub as a remote, but if there are, I'd like to learn about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BFG Repo Cleaner**

1. Download [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)
2. `bfg --delete-folders path/to/your/content my-repo.git`

**Git filter-branch**

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/your/content" \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

You'll need to do a force push once you're happy to reset any origins.

Comment: The force push indicates you _will_ have data loss (which is the whole point of this exercise though).  Have backups!

Answer (score 0):

git works by snapshotting the whole directory tree watched by git.

This mean that you cannot just manipulate history by directory but you need to do it by changing every commit in the whole repository and having everyone to check out the repository a new as all the commit sha1 hashes change.

We did this a few years back as part of moving files to fit a Maven structure and wanting the history to stay on the files, but it was a non-trivial task.

You may want to reach a suitable checkpoint, and then simply start a new repository with your current files, and leave the old repository for reference for those needed who need it.

Comment: This is a good point. I do have all the repository contributors on board and so far we're leaning towards going through with this rather than starting anew, we'd really like to avoid that. It looks like the filter-branch option is the best course of action in this case.

Comment: The filter-branch is what we did.  It is a very nice way of explicitly manipulating the files in the commit, but you have to be very careful to be certain that what is being done is what you wanted.  This is also what the BFG does, but targetting large files in commits.   I like git, it is like clay - you can do whatever you want.  Or perhaps, it is like plastic explosives - you can manipulate it like clay, but if you mishandle it, it blows up :)